# ASP.Net Accessing Masterpage properties from a custom class

Tags: asp.net, class, master-pages

A trivial question but I'm having one of those moments...

I have a masterpage (let's call it M) in a website solution. Now I want all my content pages to derive from a custom class (called B, which in turn inherits from Page).

Now the problem is, I want B to be able to access properties and methods of M (master page). Doing so in individual content pages works fine (as the methods and properties are declared public in the masterpage):

```
M mPage = (M)Page.Master;
```

But doing this in B fails. I've set the `MasterPageFile` property of B in its `PreInit` method too, so its masterpage is set correctly. As I understand it, as this is a website solution and not a web application, I'm trying to access run-time materials at compile-time which doesn't fly.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create an interface:

```
public interface IMyMasterPage { }
```

Have your master page implement it this interface, then you can do:

```
IMyMasterPage mPage = (IMyMasterPage)Page.Master;
```

Comment: Brian, you have no idea how helpful your post was in pointing me to the right direction. THANK YOU!I will post a more elaborated solution for anyone with the same problem.

Comment: For anyone struggling with this problem, there's a thread at http://forums.asp.net/t/1520880.aspx/1 which uses the concept of using interfaces as suggested by Brian. Good luck!